# CKAN2.9 add upload field to dataset (package) form

Tags: ckan

I've created an extension that allows for thumbnail images to be uploaded for CKAN datasets; however, it seems I'm stuck at getting the CKAN filestore to actually save the images. Any help would be appreciated.

##### The Code

I followed [this tutorial](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/extensions/adding-custom-fields.html) to alter the package metadata and successfully added a "thumbnail" attribute to the schema. I can see values stored there when I create a new package. Here is a sample of my extension code directly taken from the tutorial.

```py
    def _modify_package_schema(self, schema):
        schema.update({
            'thumbnail': [toolkit.get_validator('ignore_missing'),
                            toolkit.get_converter('convert_to_extras')]
        })
        return schema

    def create_package_schema(self):
        schema = super(CardThemePlugin, self).create_package_schema()
        schema = self._modify_package_schema(schema)
        return schema
    
    def update_package_schema(self):
        schema = super(CardThemePlugin, self).update_package_schema()
        schema = self._modify_package_schema(schema)
        return schema
```

##### The Templates

In `templates/package/snippets/package_basic_fields.html` I've put the following:

```html
{% ckan_extends %}
{% block package_basic_fields_custom %}
    {% block basic_fields_url %}
      {% set is_upload = (data.url_type == 'upload') %}
      {{ form.image_upload(data, errors, field_url='url', field_upload='upload', field_clear='clear_upload',
         is_upload_enabled=h.uploads_enabled(), is_url=data.url and not is_upload, is_upload=is_upload,
         upload_label=_('Thumbnail'), url_label=_('Thumbnail'), placeholder=_('http://thumbnail.png'), field_name='thumbnail') }}
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

This adds an upload field (like the ones on the organization form and the resource form) to the dataset form. This allowed me to successfully save links in my package schema and the links can be used as the `src` for the thumbnail successfully.

##### The Problem

I can't seem to find a way to get CKAN to save uploaded files. I've verified that filestore works properly (I used [this tutorial](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/maintaining/filestore.html) to set it up). So far, I've tried using the [IUploader interface](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IUploader), but this seems to only be applicable for resource and organization uploads. I also looked into calling the FileStore API using the following:

```py
import requests
requests.post('http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/action/resource_create',
              data={"package_id":"my_dataset"},
              headers={"X-CKAN-API-Key": "21a47217-6d7b-49c5-88f9-72ebd5a4d4bb"},
              files=[('upload', open(data_dict["upload"]))])
```

However, I can't find a way to access the actual uploaded file as only the name is saved by the schema so it throws a file not found error when called.

I am aware of the ckanext-datasetthumbnail extension; however, this only allows thumbnails to be uploaded as resources with the name thumbnail.png. This is not my desired behavior. If possible, I would like a working upload field on the first page of the dataset creation form. This is the current appearance, but the upload functionality does not work:

[CKAN dataset form page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlVRc.png)

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: You can get the ckan storage path (the directory that ckan stores uploaded files) and save the image there. `ckan.plugins.toolkit.config['ckan.storage_path']`  gives you the path.

Comment: Regarding the empty file uploaded (only the file name), I think you are using `request.form.get()` to get the file on your backend. You should use `request.files.get()` to get file content from client (CKAN + v.2 uses Flask. the `request` is a Flask library)